# How to format date in angular2?

Tags: date, angular

My code:

```
   this.nextDay = new Date();
   var datePipe = new DatePipe('en-US')
   this.presentDate = datePipe.transform(this.nextDay, 'YYYY-MM-DD H:mm:ss');
```

But with the above code, I am getting `this.presentDate = yyyy-3-DD 23:04:99`

I want date as 2017-3-23 23:09:06 ,but here I don't know why I got yyyy?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a single `y` and lowercase `dd`

```
this.nextDay = new Date();
var datePipe = new DatePipe('en-US')
this.presentDate = datePipe.transform(this.nextDay, 'y-MM-dd H:mm:ss');
```

Reference: https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/api/angular2.common/DatePipe-class